# How to add column before treecolumn in Qt qtreeview

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I want to add a column before the tree column.
A similar thing is visible in the picture.
But I can't find any examples of that.

[image]

Comment: What language?  What have you tried so far?  Is the project associated with the image open source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this. It is necessary to swap columns, as shown in the example. It works the same way on all Qt languages that have QTreeView.

```cpp
QTreeView *view;
view->setModel(model);
view->header()->swapSections(0, 1);
```